# Copy row and all of its 'children'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called `employees`. There's another table called `shifts` that is tied to `employees` by the `employeeId` column and a one-to-many relationship. I want to clone an employee and his shifts using `INSERT` - so the `employee` row is cloned, and the `shifts` are all cloned and have the new auto-incrementing primary key that was generated for the new `employee`. Is this possible in one query?

Comment: You probably need two, one for each table.  Or use a stored procedure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes but not with a single insert.

You'd have one INSERT to do the employee, then a second INSERT with a sub-SELECT to SELECT all of the shift data.

Here are some [examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this many times, or want to do it on a bulk level, create an sp that inserts a dupe entry for an employee and then inserts dupe entries for all his shifts.

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cloneEmployee
@employeeId int
AS
INSERT INTO employees
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE employeeId = @employeeId;

INSERT INTO shifts
SELECT * FROM shifts 
WHERE employeeId = @employeeId;
```