# Copy Row and its children and its children

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is similar to this question [Copy Row and all of its 'children'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767066/copy-row-and-all-of-its-children) but is a little (maybe a lot) more complicated.

I have a table  'Project' which contains some information and UUID. This has a 1:M relationship with table 'Checkpoint'. 'Checkpoint' then has a 1:M relationship with table 'TaskCommon'. 'TaskCommon' then has a 1:1 relationship with table 'TaskSpecific' which is joined based on its 'TaskCommonId' to it's parent.

I need to create a copy function that will take a project, copy it, then all of its checkpoints, tasks, and specifics.

I plan on using a stored procedure to do all of this and was wondering if there is a better way to do this rather than having to loop through each Checkpoint and then Task.

Is there a way some type of recursive query could be done for this?

Comment: Have you looked at [Recursive CTE's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Comment: I've used CTEs before and this was my first thought. Is it going to be beneficial to use nested CTEs over an uglier for loop?

Comment: Is there really recursion, or simply four levels: Project, Checkpoint, TaskCommon and TaskSpecific?  You can use `INSERT`/`SELECT` to copy data within a table.  Add an `OUTPUT` clause to capture the new Ids into a temporary table at each level and use it to fix up the relations as you copy the next level.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the 4 different insert statements.
1st One will copy the data from Project table.
Now use the newly copied data to join with cehckpoint to bring all the checkpoints details and copy that to your copy checkpoint table.Now follow the same for other two tables.